# Using Case When to Determine whether to update values or select values

Tags: sql, sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

**Edit**: The below question was framed incorrectly by attempting to utilize the `CASE WHEN` expression in place of an `IF` statement. Please see the answer provided by  [schmiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16019058/shmiel). Hopefully this helps others.

I'm making a tool/report in Report Builder. The main logic is dictated by a parameter that is manually selected with a dropdown called **CheckOrUpdate**.

What I'm trying to accomplish is if the **CheckOrUpdate** parameter is set to **CHECK** I want the report to run a simple Query. If set to **UPDATE** I want the report to run an update statement.

Here is the Query:

```
DECLARE @SITE AS NVARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @Password AS NVARCHAR (30)
DECLARE @CheckOrUpdate AS NVARCHAR(30)

--SET @Password = 'Resend'
--SET @SITE = 'SRVCS' 
--SET @CASE = '123456'
--SET @CheckOrUpdate = 'CHECK'

SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN @CheckOrUpdate = 'CHECK' --Just check to verify that records have been updated
        THEN
            (SELECT
            order_num
            ,is_extracted
            ,interface_batch
            ,trans.item_num
            ,item.desc_1
            ,item.desc_2

            FROM trans
            INNER JOIN item on item.item_num=trans.item_num

            WHERE order_num=@CASE AND site_code = @SITE AND is_extracted = 1 AND @Password='Resend')

    WHEN @CheckOrUpdate = 'UPDATE' --Run the update
        THEN
            (UPDATE trans
            SET is_extracted = 0 , interface_batch = NULL
            WHERE order_num=@CASE AND site_code = @SITE AND is_extracted = 1 AND @Password='Resend')
    --ELSE NOTHING
END
```

I understand that the syntax should go *SET* > *Select* > *CASE WHEN*. Just trying to understand how to go about running a query or running an update.

There is only one dataset in the report I'm making and the dataset is using the query above.
The commented out portion is where I was testing the logic in SQL Server.

Any ideas or references someone can point me too? Should I create another dataset and split the two? I couldn't find much in the way of what I'm looking to do.

*Background: Application didn't interface info for this record due to interface outage or error and queueing stuff to be resent. Now this is being done manually just creating a tool to speed the process up for end users.*

Comment: T-SQL `CASE` is not a control flow statement - it is an expression. It seems you want an `IF` statement.

Comment: You have to use IF Statements instead of CASE WHEN, CASE WHEN is just for conditions inside a SELECT Statement, but you mixed SELECT and UPDATE

Comment: Ahh thank you two! I just looked it up and explains why I wasn't able to simply search my question since I was limiting myself to just a ```CASE``` expression which is not applicable. I've got it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by [Dan Guzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711162/dan-guzman) and [droebi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11305029/droebi) you should use a `if` statement like:

```sql
if @CheckOrUpdate = 'CHECK' --Just check to verify that records have been updated
begin
    (SELECT
        order_num
        ,is_extracted
        ,interface_batch
        ,trans.item_num
        ,item.desc_1
        ,item.desc_2
    FROM trans t
    INNER JOIN item  i
    on i.item_num=t.item_num
    WHERE order_num=@CASE 
    AND site_code = @SITE 
    AND is_extracted = 1 
    AND @Password='Resend')
end
else if @CheckOrUpdate = 'UPDATE'
begin
    (UPDATE trans
    SET is_extracted = 0 , interface_batch = NULL
    WHERE order_num=@CASE AND site_code = @SITE AND is_extracted = 1 AND @Password='Resend')
end
```

Or you can use `else` instead of `else if` if you only have two options.

And maybe you don't need the `begin` and `end` statement but that's the way I'm writing `if` statements :)

Comment: Yes this is pretty much the route I've gone. Since there are only two options for the control parameter either way is good. Thank you!